# Basel problem over $\mathbb{Q}_{\geq 1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, rational-numbers

Let $\mathbb{Q}_{\geq 1}=\{r\in\mathbb{Q}\,|\,r\geq 1\}$. Once $\mathbb{Q}$ is enumerable, $\mathbb{Q}_{\geq 1}$ is also enumerable. Let $\{r_1,r_2,\ldots\}$ be such an enumeration. What can we say about

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r_n^2}$$

does it converge or does it diverge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It diverges, and the answer doesn't depend on which enumeration you use (since all the terms are positive). Indeed,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{r_n^2} = \sum_{\substack{r\in\Bbb Q \\ r\ge1}}\frac1{r^2} \ge \sum_{\substack{r\in\Bbb Q \\ 1\le r\le 2}}\frac1{r^2} \ge \sum_{\substack{r\in\Bbb Q \\ 1\le r\le 2}} \frac14,
$$
and the last sum is certainly divergent.

Comment: Yeah, because there are enumerable many rationals between $1$ and $2$. Great answer.